# Correct metasploit search usage (or bug?)

Tags: metasploit

I just noticed that the metasploit search keyword does not produce results as I'd expect it.

If I search e.g. with

```
search platform:linux
```

I get proper results limited to Linux.

But if I add another criterion it seems to combine them with OR instead of AND, as I would need it. Example:

```
search platform:linux name:SMB
```

This gives me tons of results which are not limited to Linux and also Linux results that do not have SMB in their name.

Am I using this wrong? Is my setup not working correctly? I sincerely hope this is not working as intended since with so many exploits and modules I'd really need to limit my searches by combining keywords and categories.

Comment: From a quick test, I get search defaulting to an "and" search - what version of Metasploit are you using?

Comment: I've always had it OR search rather than AND. Annoying. IIRC, if you disconnect it from the DB, it will use its internal search logic instead of the DBs and go back to AND searches.

Comment: Framework: 4.11.12-dev; Console  : 4.11.12-dev.15168. I'm using the Kali 2 virtualbox image, it's got the latest updates via aptitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior changed in December 2016. `search` now returns an intersection of results for multiple keywords instead of a union.

Comment: Is there a changelog for this? Just wondering if they've done any other helpful things which improve the search!

Comment: This is the PR that implemented the change: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/pull/7647

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have to check it out. This way metasploit might just have become usable for me.