# metasploit search command to fetch one AND another word

Tags: metasploit

Is there a way to use **metasploit** console to search for 2 words exclusively?

For example:
`search X and Y` //I don't know if the syntax is this, of course

In a way that will only return exploits that has both `X` and `Y`?

Comment: Similar question [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/116400/8340) with no answer unfortunately.

Comment: Did you try to check msf > help search - Usage: search [options] [regex] - try also this symbol &. If there is no chance to do that, then write your own bash script.

Comment: Have you looked at the msf console's grep command? Together with search you can grep but multiple keywords if you want